# ng snotify not showing toaster after login

Tags: angular, snotify

I am building a sample application in angular 11 in which I have implemented **ng snotify** to generate toaster for empty login(no credentials), incorrect login & valid login. The **ng snotify** toaster is working fine for invalid credentials but it is not working for valid login credentials and for empty credentials it sometimes show both the toaster for empty credentials as well as login successful toaster all together which is technically incorrect.
Below are the code files for better understanding

**login.component.ts**

```
// @ts-ignore
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { SnotifyService } from "ng-snotify";

/*import {userInfo} from "os";*/

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  /*Properties*/
  loading: boolean = false;
  action: string = '';
  private index: number = 0;

  constructor(public authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private cookieService: CookieService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
    private snotifyService: SnotifyService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  signIn($event: any, email: string, pass: string): void {
    this.loading = true;
    const data = {
      userName: email,
      password: pass
    };

    if (data.userName === '' || data.password === '') {
      this.loading = false;

      this.snotifyService.warning('Username & Password cannot be empty', '', {
        timeout: 7000,
        showProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: false,
        pauseOnHover: true
      });

      $event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      this.authService.logIn(data).subscribe(response => {
        if (response.isValid == true) {
          this.cookieService.set('username', response.username);
          this.cookieService.set('password', response.username);
          this.cookieService.set('userId', response.id);
          this.cookieService.set('isLoggedIn', response.isValid);


          this.snotifyService.success('Logged in successfully!', '', {
            timeout: 7000,
            showProgressBar: false,
            closeOnClick: false,
            pauseOnHover: true
          });


          this.router.navigateByUrl('/db');
          this.loading = false;
        } else {
          this.loading = false;

          this.snotifyService.error('Invalid Username or Password !', '', {
            timeout: 7000,
            showProgressBar: false,
            closeOnClick: false,
            pauseOnHover: true
          });
        }
      }, error => {
        this.loading = false;
      });
      $event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Empty Login Snotify toaster]

[image: Invalid credentials snotify toaster]
[image: Successful login but no snotify display]

**any solution please ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you navigate to another page so you basically not "seeing" the success notify (it just happened fast and right after it making the redirect).

```
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/db');
```

you can make it by subscribing to the other page or just when the /db is up (when it login - redirect and after the login component is up (with afterViewInit) you can make the notify.

Comment: Medinios: where i have to implement afterView in login component or the compnent that gets displayed after login ?

Comment: in the component that gets displayed after the login.

Comment: Medinios : Thank you brother, it is working but one thing is that sometimes it shows two toaster 'Logged in successfully!' after login. Any solution for this ?

Comment: yes, you have to make it pop up only after you make the login, you can make it with several solutions - one solution is with a flag will say " hi I just logged in" and when it happened send a notify (maybe with local storage (delete after the notify / subject ) btw If that's the answer mark it with the green v :)

Comment: Medinios: can you please give an example like how  ?

Comment: Medinios: Thank you brother I have marked with green :)